# zabbix track application uptime

Tags: zabbix

I want to have a separate item/metric that will track my application uptime.

https://sketch.io/render/sk-8f1ef25fb0b34c26cfc9a7aa283cb3ab.jpeg

My application is UP, if all 5 triggers related to that application are UP, if any one of those triggers is in the DOWN state then the application is DOWN.

Why do i want that?

The primary reason is to quickly check when my app was up without the need to look at each individual trigger history. I don't really care if the app was down because of the lost connection to the database or we were out of memory, I just need to know when that happened and for how long.

So the question is: How to populate an item based on trigger status

Answer (score 1):

This is called event correlation in Zabbix. In your case, trigger-based event correlation.
Check the documentation about this : https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/event_correlation/trigger